# add property values in jena

Tags: jena, protege

how could i add property values in to individuals. i created a new individual called "laknath". then after i need to add the property values to it..

OntClass cul = model.getOntClass("http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1275995702.owl#person");

Individual ind = model.createIndividual("http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1275995702.owl#laknath",cul);

i have to add URL under that individuals(ind).. there may be one or many URL's belongs to that person...how can i add that:::

can any one tell me the way..

Comment: it is a datatype property values.

Answer (score 2):

```
Property myproperty = model.getProperty("http://whatever/myontology.owl#myproperty");
ind.addProperty(myproperty, "value");
```

Comment: i need to get the data type property value.. problem solved now. thanks for reply